# How to pass arguments to BuiltIn().run_keyword() for keyword name with embedded arguments

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework, currently I tried the python function BuiltIn().run_keyword() to run keywords in *.robot file.
For example, I have a keyword in my robot file

```
Select Anything From Here
```

and it works fine when I call in my python file

```
BuiltIn().run_keyword("Select Anything From Here")
```

Now, I have another keyword with two embedded parameters in the name itself

```
Select ${animal} From Here by ${user}
```

What should I pass to the run_keyword() ?

I found the document about the run_keyword(name, *args) but I tried, it did not work out with my keyword with embedded parameters.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You do it exactly the way you would call it from robot:

```
BuiltIn().run_keyword("Select cow from here by Old McDonald")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works! You answered my question :)

Comment: Now If I have another keyword with double quotes to the parameter, is it possible to call it by BuiltIn().run_keyword() ?
 E.g. Select "${animal}" From Here

Comment: @OceaniaWater: my answer doesn't change: you still call it exactly like you would from robot.